# Auto reload iframe on main window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am working on this website about a pub and I made the menu as a slider, but the problem is that when the window gets resized the iframes themselves don't. I don't know exactly how to explain it but you can take a look here:

http://raduadrian.com/square101/

Scroll down to the menu , and you'll see that it looks fine , if you resize the window it will mess up but , if you resize it and then refresh the page it will look okay on that width until you resize again.

Any ideas how this could be fixed?

If you need any of the code let me know but I basically used bx slider found here: http://bxslider.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    document.getElementById('FrameID').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
});
```

With multiple iframes you can use classes instead of id's.